# Possible to query database on WP table sort?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a query argument like this:

```
<?php
    return array(
      "post_type" => "wpdmpro",
      "post_status" => "publish",
      "orderby" => "title",
      "order" => "ASC",
      "posts_per_page" => 50
);
```

and am currently adding the tablesorter plug in functionality to the table. It sorts client side and only shuffles the items already on the page. Is there a good way to re-query the database to the desired sort and return data that way? Fore example if I am using the page title and it returns names from A-D and I want to sort it currently just shuffles to D-A. How would I sort **server side** so that when I toggle the name column it would query the database and return starting with Z (from the bottom, **not just what is on page currently**)?

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you mean? But going from your request "How would I sort by name and have it return starting with Z?" just change:

```
"order" => "ASC",
```

to:

```
"order" => "DESC",
```

But this is not client side off course. The Table Sorter plugin is not executing server side query. It just sorts the results on the page itself. And therefore only the 50 posts shown.

I guess you would have to write your own function that does query the database again but then in reverse order (desc). This would require a page reload, or your function should be executed with ajax.

Comment: Right, I have that part. I want to sort server side, my apologies for not stating that clearly. Thank you.

Comment: No, I was looking for server side sorting. Tablesorter isnt going to do what I need. Looking for examples of serverside or ajax sorting, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I Have tried This will Help for you.

```
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'title',
'order'   => 'DESC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: please add details